# jQuery: How to add event handler to dynamically added HTML elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function({
    $(".click").click(function(){
        alert(' The Button Was Clicked !');
    });
}));
```

This works fine.
But If I add an element with the same class to the web page,  as shown here:

```
$('#clicked').click(function(){
    $("#area").append("<button class='click'>Click me</button>");
});
```

Then the event handler I added before to the .click class won't work for this new element. 
What's that best way to add event handlers to elements that were added dynamically ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**UPDATE**

It's been a while since I posted this answer and things have changed by now:

```
$(document).on('click', '.click', function() {

});
```

Since jQuery 1.7+ the new `.on()` should be used and `.live()` is deprecated. The general rule of thumb is:

- Don't use `.live()` unless your jQuery version doesn't support `.delegate()`.
- Don't use `.delegate()` unless your jQuery version doesn't support `.on()`.

Also check out this [benchmark](http://jsperf.com/jquery-live-vs-delegate-vs-on) to see the difference in performance and you will see why you should not use `.live()`.

---

Below is my original answer:

use either delegate or live

```
$('.click').live('click', function(){
});
```

or

```
$('body').delegate('.click', 'click', function() {

});
```

Comment: Ah! I was just a minute too late : )

Comment: @Banx: Even 2 minutes. Wow you're slow ;)

Comment: I know, I have to step my game up : )

Answer (score 5):

In reference to your code, the way to do it would be.

```
$('.click').live('click', function(){
  ... do cool stuff here
});
```

Using the .live() function allows you to dynamically attach event handlers to DOM objects. 
Have fun!

Answer (score 2):

for all the elements added dynamically to DOM at run time , please use live

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 2):

After jQuery 1.7 the live method just points to .on() method. And I had alot trouble finding out how to bind event handler to element which is appended to the DOM after its loaded.

```
$('body').live('click', '.click', function(){
   //Your code
});
```

This worked for me. Just a little tip for those having trouble with it also.