# "on" event not firing with dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below code which using jquery *on* event.

```
    $(document).on('click', 'a.test', function (event) {
        alert('');
    });
```

My issue is that this is not firing for the content which is added dynamically via ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: ...,
    ...
    ..
    success: function(response) {

        var dom = $(response.d.html);
        myContainer.html(dom.find('#ajaxcontainer'));
    }
});
```

Can you help me fixing this? I am using jquery.1.7.2.min.js

Comment: Where/when is this `.on()` executed? Does it come with the dynamic content or is it attached beforehand? What does the response data look like?

Comment: take a look at `live()` http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: on click of anchors with "test" class.

Comment: `.live()` is **[already deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/)** and replaced by `.on()`. I wonder why `.live()` was even suggested.

Comment: Can you show your html ?

Comment: also, you'll need an event.preventDefault();

Comment: Can you show us the code as to *when* the `.on()` is attached and the HTML that is loaded via AJAX.

Comment: Its working for me: http://jsfiddle.net/5nxfx/ something maybe with your html?

Comment: @Phil You might be interested in reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772018/jquery-add-event-handler/5772031#5772031).

Comment: Wow, haha, I haven't touched `jQuery` in... 3 months? Gosh internet timeline... Thank guys!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not having any problems strangely enough... I think you might need to be calling your ajax like a function on that .on('click') event.

[jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/BEdwW/)

```
var myContainer = $('body');

$(document).on('click', 'a', function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: '#',
    success: function(response) {
        // of course here i'm appending just a regular link, but your response data would include all that html
        myContainer.append('<a class="ajaxAdded">Click this</a>');

    }
  });
});
```

​

Comment: It should just work from within the `.on()` function.

Comment: Yeah it does, i just figured for separation purposes to have it outside of it (incase you want something else to call it too). But it works inside .on() too.  http://jsfiddle.net/BEdwW/

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that as `$.ajax` it's an asynchronous function your `on` method can't access to the content it creates perhaps because that content isn't ready yet you need to make sure you have already completed the ajax request for the event to fire, you can do something like this to check that out:

```
var done = false;
$.ajax({ /*bla bla bla*/ }).done(function(){ done = true; });

if(done){/* now you can fire the event */ }
```