# How to detect when a text input changes with ie8

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to detect when a text input changes.
I tried these, which worked in firefox but not in ie 8.

```
$('#taskSearch').bind('input', function() {
     alert($(this).val());
});
$('#taskSearch').live('input', function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
$('#taskSearch').change(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/change/ ...

Comment: BTW , you forgot to `)`: `alert($(this).val();` => `alert($(this).val());`
Maybe this is the reason it doesn't work

Comment: Is `#taskSearch` your text box?

Answer (score 11):

You can use `onpropertychange` for IE6+:

```
$("#taskSearch").on("propertychange", function(){
alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: This is the only event that fired for me out of all the answers in IE8, it seems to fire multiple times for each keystroke.

Comment: Litte remark: You can not use on("propertychange change keyup") - more than one event with space separated list in some browsers I guess.

Comment: $("#taskSearch").on("propertychange input", function(){}); works well for me in modern browsers and < IE9.

Answer (score 3):

The following solution works for me in IE8 and modern browsers for both changes by keys, scroll or the arrow buttons within the a type="num" input field:

```
$('#element').on('keyup change', function() {
  // do something
});
```

Comment: This one worked for me. While `propertychange` has worked for me in the past, it also fires if the user changes other properties, like `disabled`. My AJAX function would disable and then re-enable the text box when validating, which would in turn fire `propertychange`, resulting in a very frustrating loop. These events resolved it for me.

Answer (score 2):

The last one (and only the last one) is correct, but you were missing a closing parenthesis:

```
$('#taskSearch').change(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

`.live()` is deprecated (and the syntax is incorrect), and the syntax for `.bind()` is also incorrect; the name of the event is `'change'`, not `'input'`. See the documentation for [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).

Comment: There is an `input` event in most browsers which unlike `change` fires before the input loses focus, so it's possible that that is what the OP was intending to use.

Comment: @tim Thanks, I didn't know about that one, I assume(d) he was using it as a selector. I don't know that jQuery supports that event, in any case...it could just pass-through the browser method though. That would certainly explain why OP's code ran in FF but not IE

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/spicyj/jquery-splendid-textchange is a plug-in to fix the quirks of emulating "input" in IE8 and IE9.

The author described how he achieved this solution in his blog post (http://benalpert.com/2013/06/18/a-near-perfect-oninput-shim-for-ie-8-and-9.html), which is indeed complex, have a read if you want to know the details.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#taskSearch').change(function() {
    alert($(this).val()); // not the extra brace I've added
});
```

Should just work. P.S. [please stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772018/jquery-add-event-handler/5772031#5772031) using [`.live()`](http://jsperf.com/jquery-live-vs-delegate-vs-on).

Answer (score 0):

This will detect when the key is pressed in IE8

$("#input").on('keyup', function (event) { alert('keypress');  });

Answer (score 0):

To fire immediately on input value change:

```
$('#example')on('keyup input', function(e){
    alert(e.type); // Displays 'keyup' in IE8, 'input' in browsers
});
```

(This is a variation of Mark's answer)